# python pickle issue with cron job

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

I am using python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to create an object and store in config file. Without cron job, I am able to run the script and able to generate config.pkl. However, once I put it in cron job and I am not able to generate config.pkl, but the log "calling generateConfig" is generated. The file has the execute permission.

Below are the function and cron job.

```
def generateConfig():
       print "calling generateConfig"
       configDict = {"test1":"value1","test2":"value2"}
       output = open('config.pkl','wb')
       pickle.dump(configDict, output)
       output.close
```

crontab:

```
00 05 * * * /user/bin/python ~/job/process.py
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `python` is in `/user/bin` in your platform? In most Linux, it is usually in `/usr/bin`. Are you also absolutely sure that the cronjob generated the `"calling generateConfig"` and not a residue of a manual run?

Comment: Hi @alvits, sorry, my typo in this forum. I double checked and cron job is /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing a path for `config.pkl`, my guess would be it's going to dump that file into the home directory of the user running it; if it's not being put there, try searching your system. If no error is being logged then it's likely that file is somewhere, just not where you're expecting it to be.

It's also good practice to wrap anything that could generate an exception (writing files, for instance) in a `try`/`catch` and explicitly either handling or logging problems so you at least maintain control over your script's execution; in this case, if you ended up attempting to pickle a resource, your script could die without closing that file handle. Using '`with open(...) as output:` is a good option.

Comment: Hi @kungphu, should I hard code the path for config.pkl? I tried output = open('~/job/config.pkl','wb') but still cannot find in ~/job directory

Comment: Have you searched the relevant user's home directory? I'd suggest starting with hard-coding, for example, `open('/tmp/config.pkl', 'wb')` and seeing if the file shows up in tmp. If it does, then it's likely a path/configuration problem, and you'll want to either use an absolute rather than relative path. If not, there's something else going wrong, and more output/error catching may be in order for diagnosis.